# With fontspec, how can one define a variation of a font family?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I keep running into the following situation using [*fontspec*](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) with *XeTeX*:

- I define a "base" font family using `\newfontfamily`.
- I then want to access a "spaced small caps" variant, using the `LetterSpace` feature within the `SmallCapsFeatures` set.
- I then want to define yet another variation on the former small caps spacing settings, for use in a different context within the paragraph.

So far, the only way I've figured out how to do this is to define *wholly separate font families* for each of these three variations (no adjustment to spacing, one adjustment to spacing, and some other adjustment to spacing), like so:

```
\setmainfont[BoldFont={* Semibold},
             Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
            {Adobe Garamond Pro}

\newfontfamily\rmaltfamily
  [BoldFont={* Semibold},
   Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
   SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=2.5}]
  {Adobe Garamond Pro}

\newfontfamily\rmaltloosefamily
  [BoldFont={* Semibold},
   Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
   SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=4.0}]
  {Adobe Garamond Pro}
```

In the spirit of not repeating oneself, that's just awful. The only thing I *intend* to change between those is the presence and value of the `LetterSpace` feature.

I tried using the `\addfontfeature` command as shown in Example 42 in [the fontspec manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) to *layer* these changes over the current font, but, despite what the manual suggests, at least with my fonts, the `LetterSpace` feature is only available for specification within the `SmallCapsFeature` set, which is in turn only available for specification within either the `\newfontfamily` or `\fontspec` commands.

For reference here, the manual advertises that the following should be possible:

```
\fontspec{Didot}
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=0.0}
USE TRACKING FOR DISPLAY CAPS TEXT \\
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2.0}
USE TRACKING FOR DISPLAY CAPS TEXT
```

Though my three separate `\fontfamily` definitions do work, it feels like the wrong tool for the job. Is there some better way to define a basic font family and then layer in a few changes in it, such that those changes can be used in certain contexts and be restricted in scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={* Semibold},
             Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
            {Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}

{\scshape Abcde fghi}

{\addfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=2.5}}\scshape Abcde fghi \upshape Abcde fghi}

{\addfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=4.0}}\scshape Abcde fghi \upshape Abcde fghi}

\end{document}
```

The small caps words are letter spaced, those in upright shape aren't.

[image]

As far as I know, it's not possible to define a new font family as a variant of another, but something like

```
\newcommand{\spacedsc}{\normalfont
  \addfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=2.5}}%
  \scshape}
```

is quite similar. From the `.log` file I can see that **fontspec** doesn't recompute the font assignments once this variation is used; in other words each subsequent use of `\spacedsc` will load the font family computed the first time. Maybe Will Robertson can be more precise on the question.

Comment: And now that works for me too. I think I was using the wrong delimiters, with some left and right brackets (`[` and `]`) instead of the curly braces. Well, if I discover that that wasn't the only problem, I'll come back and update the question with the motivating test case. For now, though, thank you.

Comment: More broadly, though, is there any way to define another font family in terms of a previously-defined one, so that the second definition comprises the first plus a few overriding modifications?

Comment: See edited answer.