# Windows/Unix Xelatex font usage with fontspec and ttf fonts semi-bold weight

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, fontspec, unix

I'm trying to write a file, that compiles both on windows and unix (I'm using the alpine-tinytex image, but the answer should be portable across *nix).

I would like to use the semi-bold fontface of the `Inconsolata` google-font using XeLaTeX. For Windows I installed it manually, in Alpine, I used

`apk add ttf-inconsolata`

Using  `\newfontfamily\codefont{Inconsolata}` I can use the font in Unix, and even changing the weight to the standard variants (e.g. bold using `\textbf{}`) but I'm unable to use semi-bold. All answers to enable non-standard weights (such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62603/how-to-choose-a-specific-weight-from-a-font-family-using-fontspec-and-xelatex) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24450/with-fontspec-how-can-one-define-a-variation-of-a-font-family) seem to rely on loading a different sub-font.

I've tried

1. `\newfontfamily\codefont{Inconsolata Semi Bold}`

which doesn't work on Windows (font not found error).

2. `\newfontfamily\codefont{Inconsolata SemiBold}`

which works on Windows but fails on Linux with

`Package fontspec Error: The font "Inconsolata SemiBold" cannot be found.`

3. `\newfontfamily\codefont{Inconsolata-SemiBold}` (which is the name of the ttf. variant according to the font's documentation)

which works on Windows but fails on Linux with `kpathsea` stating:`

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata-SemiBold
/home/appuser/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for Inconsolata-SemiBold.
/home/appuser/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Inconsolata-SemiBold
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata-SemiBold

! I can't find file `Inconsolata-SemiBold'.
<*> ...; ; nonstopmode; input Inconsolata-SemiBold
```

which I think is the closest to a solution but still I seem to miss something.

**Edit:**

4. `\newfontfamily\codefont{Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf}` works on Windows but fails on Unix with:

```
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf]/OT', contains '['
[...]
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Inconsolata-SemiBold" cannot be found.
[...]    
! Font TU/Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf(0)/m/n/10.95=[Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf]/OT a
t 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
<to be read again>
```

Comment: typically with xelatex it is best to use the file name and not the font name, so `XXX.ttf`.

Comment: That gives another error @UlrikeFischer which hints that maybe the fontsize is wrong?

Comment: well is the font somewhere where xelatex finds it? And did you write the name correctly (linux is case sensitive).

Comment: Indeed the font is not on the system as it wasn't installed by the `ttf-inconsolata`  package which only installs regular and bold versions. Thanks @UlrikeFischer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is working for me and is portable across Windows and Unix.

I installed Inconsolata as a font from the packages. In ubuntu, `apt-get install fonts-inconsolata` installs the `.otf` version of the font - in e.g. alpine `apk add ttf-inconsolata` installs only the regular and bold weights of the font. There are several answers here on how to use different weights with `.otf` fonts, however none of them seem to be compatible with a `.tex` file that compiles under windows.

So, I manually installed the needed font variant (in my case `Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf`) by copying both to `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf` as well as `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf`. This way I can directly choose the font or use it as the semi-bold variant of Inconsolata (e.g. inside listings) automatically.

For this to work, the fonts have to have the correct permissions (`chmod 644`) and the font-cache has to be updated (e.g. `/usr/bin/fc-cache -fv`).

Inside my `.tex` file both versions of

```
\newfontfamily\codefont{Inconsolata-SemiBold}
\newfontfamily\listingfont{Inconsolata}
```

and e.g. using semi-bold inside `lstlisting` works on Windows and *nix.